# ASCII code in batch file, doesn't seem to print right no matter what i try

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

```
echo██▓███   ▄▄▄        ██▀███   ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ▒█████  ▒██   ██▒
echo▓██░  ██▒▒████▄    ▓██ ▒ ██▒▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▒██▒  ██▒▒▒ █ █ ▒░
echo▓██░ ██▓▒▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██ ░▄█ ▒▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌▒██░  ██▒░░  █   ░
echo▒██▄█▓▒ ▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██▀▀█▄  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌▒██   ██░ ░ █ █ ▒ 
echo▒██▒ ░  ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██▓ ▒██▒ ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓ ░ ████▓▒░▒██▒ ▒██▒
echo▒▓▒░ ░  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒ ░ ▒░▒░▒░ ▒▒ ░ ░▓ ░
echo░▒ ░       ▒   ▒▒ ░  ░▒ ░ ▒░  ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒   ░ ▒ ▒░ ░░   ░▒ ░
echo░░         ░   ▒     ░░   ░   ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒   ░    ░  
echo░  ░   ░           ░  ░   ░        ░ ░   ░    ░  
echo                                   ░
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want to acheive and show the code that you used?

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 6):

> - To obtain the desired result, check the results by changing the font settings until you find the one that best fits what you want.

[image]

[image]

- By using font **[consolas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas)** without using/disable ***[ ] Bold fonts***, you get this result:

[image]

- By using font ***Courier New*** with/enable ***[√] Bold fonts***, you get this result:

[image]

[image]

---

> - After that, the code part is easier.

1. Set screen `color` background to `0` (black), and foreground to `A` (green)

```bat
color 0A
```

2. Set the display screen to the active code page number `65001`

```bat
 "%__APPDIR__%chcp.com" 65001
```

Remove windows `title <nul` and add your custom windows `title PARADOX`

```bat
title <nul & title PARADOX
```

3. Set the number of columns and rows in your window to match the logo screen

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%mode.com" 66,13
```

4. You can also add a small delay to the `echo` command, giving your logo an extra effect...

```bat
  <con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "echo[....
```

---

- For a normal output without effect, just remove all quotes and

```bat
  <con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c " echo[....
```

```bat
@echo off & color 0A & "%__APPDIR__%chcp.com" 65001 >nul & title <nul & title PARADOX && "%__APPDIR__%mode.com" 66,13
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[██▓███   ▄▄▄        ██▀███   ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ▒█████  ▒██   ██▒"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[▓██░  ██▒▒████▄    ▓██ ▒ ██▒▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▒██▒  ██▒▒▒ █ █ ▒░"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[▓██░ ██▓▒▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██ ░▄█ ▒▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌▒██░  ██▒░░  █   ░"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[▒██▄█▓▒ ▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██▀▀█▄  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌▒██   ██░ ░ █ █ ▒ "
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[▒██▒ ░  ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██▓ ▒██▒ ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓ ░ ████▓▒░▒██▒ ▒██▒"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[▒▓▒░ ░  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒ ░ ▒░▒░▒░ ▒▒ ░ ░▓ ░"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[░▒ ░       ▒   ▒▒ ░  ░▒ ░ ▒░  ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒   ░ ▒ ▒░ ░░   ░▒ ░"
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[░░         ░   ▒     ░░   ░   ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒   ░    ░  "
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[░  ░   ░           ░  ░   ░        ░ ░   ░    ░                 "
<con: call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c" echo[                                   ░                            "
```

> - **Obs.:** Consider accepting advice (about `UTF-8`/encoding) and also the  **[@JustAMartin](https://superuser.com/users/129524/justamartin)** **[answer](https://superuser.com/a/1545990/969781)**

[image]

---

If you want to prevent any further editing on the file, and thus prevent changes in the encoding of the file's content and code, you can also save your final version by encoding in base64.

But first, you need to add a final line to your bat before encoding, that is, to tell it to be excluded itself after execution:

```bat
del /q /f "%~f0" 2>&1>nul
```

Then you can generate the file encoding in base64 and copy it to the clipboard:

```bat
2>nul >nul %__APPDIR__%certutil.exe -f -encode "Q1546041.cmd" "Q1546041.b64"
type "Q1546041.b64"|clip
```

Create a new file with a command line that decodes the base64 strings embedded in it, generating a bat in the temporary folder, and also calling it to run simultaneously leaving, leaving only the decoded bat running:

```bat
@"%__APPDIR__%certutil.exe" -f -decode "%~f0" "%temp%\%~nx0" 2>&1>nul && (call 2>nul "%temp%\%~nx0" & goto :EOF)|| @exit /b

-----BEGIN Paradox-----   QGVjaG8gb2ZmICYgY2xzICYmICIlX19BUFBESVJfXyVjaGNwLmNvbSIgNjUwMDEgPm51bCAmJiB0aXRsZSA8bnVsICYmIHRpd
GxlIFBBUkFET1ggJiA+bnVsICIlX19BUFBESVJfXyVtb2RlLmNvbSIgNjYsMTMgJiBjb2xvciBBMCANCjxjb246IGNkLiAmIGNhbGwgIiV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3Rl
bTMyXGNtZC5leGUiIC91L3MvYyAiY2QuICYgZWNob1sgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA
gICAgICINCjxjb246IGNkLiAmIGNhbGwgIiV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3RlbTMyXGNtZC5leGUiIC91L3MvYyAiY2QuICYgZWNob1vilojilojilpPilojilojiloggIC
DiloTiloTiloQgICAgICAgIOKWiOKWiOKWgOKWiOKWiOKWiCAgIOKWhOKWhOKWhCAgICAgIOKWk+KWiOKWiOKWiOKWiOKWiOKWhCAg4paS4paI4paI4paI4paI4
paIICDilpLilojiloggICDilojilojilpIgIg0KPGNvbjogY2QuICYgY2FsbCAiJXdpbmRpciVcc3lzdGVtMzJcY21kLmV4ZSIgL3Uvcy9jICJjZC4gJiBlY2hv
W+KWk+KWiOKWiOKWkSAg4paI4paI4paS4paS4paI4paI4paI4paI4paEICAgIOKWk+KWiOKWiCDilpIg4paI4paI4paS4paS4paI4paI4paI4paI4paEICAgIOK
WkuKWiOKWiOKWgCDilojilojilozilpLilojilojilpIgIOKWiOKWiOKWkuKWkuKWkiDilogg4paIIOKWkuKWkSAiDQo8Y29uOiBjZC4gJiBjYWxsICIld2luZG
lyJVxzeXN0ZW0zMlxjbWQuZXhlIiAvdS9zL2MgImNkLiAmIGVjaG9b4paT4paI4paI4paRIOKWiOKWiOKWk+KWkuKWkuKWiOKWiCAg4paA4paI4paEICDilpPil
ojilogg4paR4paE4paIIOKWkuKWkuKWiOKWiCAg4paA4paI4paEICDilpHilojiloggICDilojilozilpLilojilojilpEgIOKWiOKWiOKWkuKWkeKWkSAg4paI
ICAg4paRICINCjxjb246IGNkLiAmIGNhbGwgIiV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3RlbTMyXGNtZC5leGUiIC91L3MvYyAiY2QuICYgZWNob1vilpLilojilojiloTilojilpP
ilpIg4paS4paR4paI4paI4paE4paE4paE4paE4paI4paIIOKWkuKWiOKWiOKWgOKWgOKWiOKWhCAg4paR4paI4paI4paE4paE4paE4paE4paI4paIIOKWkeKWk+
KWiOKWhCAgIOKWjOKWkuKWiOKWiCAgIOKWiOKWiOKWkSDilpEg4paIIOKWiCDilpIgICINCjxjb246IGNkLiAmIGNhbGwgIiV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3RlbTMyXGNtZ
C5leGUiIC91L3MvYyAiY2QuICYgZWNob1vilpLilojilojilpIg4paRICDilpEg4paT4paIICAg4paT4paI4paI4paS4paR4paI4paI4paTIOKWkuKWiOKWiOKW
kiDilpPiloggICDilpPilojilojilpLilpHilpLilojilojilojilojilpMg4paRIOKWiOKWiOKWiOKWiOKWk+KWkuKWkeKWkuKWiOKWiOKWkiDilpLilojiloj
ilpIgIg0KPGNvbjogY2QuICYgY2FsbCAiJXdpbmRpciVcc3lzdGVtMzJcY21kLmV4ZSIgL3Uvcy9jICJjZC4gJiBlY2hvW+KWkuKWk+KWkuKWkSDilpEgIOKWkS
DilpLilpIgICDilpPilpLilojilpHilpEg4paS4paTIOKWkeKWkuKWk+KWkSDilpLilpIgICDilpPilpLilojilpEg4paS4paS4paTICDilpIg4paRIOKWkuKWk
eKWkuKWkeKWkuKWkSDilpLilpIg4paRIOKWkeKWkyDilpEgIg0KPGNvbjogY2QuICYgY2FsbCAiJXdpbmRpciVcc3lzdGVtMzJcY21kLmV4ZSIgL3Uvcy9jICJj
ZC4gJiBlY2hvW+KWkeKWkiDilpEgICAgICAg4paSICAg4paS4paSIOKWkSAg4paR4paSIOKWkSDilpLilpEgIOKWkiAgIOKWkuKWkiDilpEg4paRIOKWkiAg4pa
SICAg4paRIOKWkiDilpLilpEg4paR4paRICAg4paR4paSIOKWkSAiDQo8Y29uOiBjZC4gJiBjYWxsICIld2luZGlyJVxzeXN0ZW0zMlxjbWQuZXhlIiAvdS9zL2
MgImNkLiAmIGVjaG9b4paR4paRICAgICAgICAg4paRICAg4paSICAgICDilpHilpEgICDilpEgICDilpEgICDilpIgICAg4paRIOKWkSAg4paRIOKWkSDilpEg4
paRIOKWkiAgIOKWkSAgICDilpEgICAiDQo8Y29uOiBjZC4gJiBjYWxsICIld2luZGlyJVxzeXN0ZW0zMlxjbWQuZXhlIiAvdS9zL2MgImNkLiAmIGVjaG9b4paR
ICDilpEgICDilpEgICAgICAgICAgIOKWkSAg4paRICAg4paRICAgICAgICDilpEg4paRICAg4paRICAgIOKWkSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICINCjxjb246IGN
kLiAmIGNhbGwgIiV3aW5kaXIlXHN5c3RlbTMyXGNtZC5leGUiIC91L3MvYyAiY2QuICYgZWNob1sgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIO
KWkSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIg0KPGNvbjogY2QuICYgY2FsbCAiJXdpbmRpciVcc3lzdGVtMzJcY21kLmV4ZSIgL3Uvcy9jICIiJXdpb
mRpciVcc3lzdGVtMzJcdGltZW91dC5leGUiIDIgPm51bCAmIGNvbG9yIEY0ICYgZGVsIC9xIC9mICIlfmYwIjI+JjE+bnVsIg==   -----END Paradox-----
```

---

The results of the generated outputs are the same

[image]

---

- The base64 string above results in this code:

```bat
@echo off & cls && "%__APPDIR__%chcp.com" 65001 >nul && title <nul && title PARADOX & >nul "%__APPDIR__%mode.com" 66,13 & color A0 
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[                                                                 "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[██▓███   ▄▄▄        ██▀███   ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ▒█████  ▒██   ██▒ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[▓██░  ██▒▒████▄    ▓██ ▒ ██▒▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▒██▒  ██▒▒▒ █ █ ▒░ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[▓██░ ██▓▒▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██ ░▄█ ▒▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌▒██░  ██▒░░  █   ░ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[▒██▄█▓▒ ▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██▀▀█▄  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌▒██   ██░ ░ █ █ ▒  "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[▒██▒ ░  ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██▓ ▒██▒ ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓ ░ ████▓▒░▒██▒ ▒██▒ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[▒▓▒░ ░  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒ ░ ▒░▒░▒░ ▒▒ ░ ░▓ ░ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[░▒ ░       ▒   ▒▒ ░  ░▒ ░ ▒░  ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒   ░ ▒ ▒░ ░░   ░▒ ░ "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[░░         ░   ▒     ░░   ░   ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒   ░    ░   "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[░  ░   ░           ░  ░   ░        ░ ░   ░    ░                  "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c "cd. & echo[                                   ░                             "
<con: cd. & call "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /u/s/c ""%windir%\system32\timeout.exe" 2 >nul & color F4 & del /q /f "%~f0"2>&1>nul"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[What is `cmd /s` for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866962/what-is-cmd-s-for)**

  [√] **[Start batch file with /u](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15594414/always-start-batch-file-with-u)**

  [√] **[CertUtil /dostips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8521)**

  [√] **[Unicode, UTF, ASCII, ANSI format differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/700221/8177207)**

  [√] **[Base64 Encode or Decode (MacOS/Windows/Linux)](https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/26/base64-encode-or-decode-on-the-command-line-without-installing-extra-tools-on-linux-windows-or-macos/)**

Answer (score 3):

There are two issues why it's not working:

1. You have an error in your code. You need a space symbol after every `echo`
2. For some reason, I found that these symbols seem to not work well with ASCII codepage in Windows 10 console. Which might mean those particular symbols, as you pasted them in your question, are not part of a standard ASCII codepage. But they work fine if I put the console into Unicode mode.

Here's what I did. I opened Notepad and copied the following code into it:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001

echo ██▓███   ▄▄▄        ██▀███   ▄▄▄      ▓█████▄  ▒█████  ▒██   ██▒
echo ▓██░  ██▒▒████▄    ▓██ ▒ ██▒▒████▄    ▒██▀ ██▌▒██▒  ██▒▒▒ █ █ ▒░
echo ▓██░ ██▓▒▒██  ▀█▄  ▓██ ░▄█ ▒▒██  ▀█▄  ░██   █▌▒██░  ██▒░░  █   ░
echo ▒██▄█▓▒ ▒░██▄▄▄▄██ ▒██▀▀█▄  ░██▄▄▄▄██ ░▓█▄   ▌▒██   ██░ ░ █ █ ▒ 
echo ▒██▒ ░  ░ ▓█   ▓██▒░██▓ ▒██▒ ▓█   ▓██▒░▒████▓ ░ ████▓▒░▒██▒ ▒██▒
echo ▒▓▒░ ░  ░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░░ ▒▓ ░▒▓░ ▒▒   ▓▒█░ ▒▒▓  ▒ ░ ▒░▒░▒░ ▒▒ ░ ░▓ ░
echo ░▒ ░       ▒   ▒▒ ░  ░▒ ░ ▒░  ▒   ▒▒ ░ ░ ▒  ▒   ░ ▒ ▒░ ░░   ░▒ ░
echo ░░         ░   ▒     ░░   ░   ░   ▒    ░ ░  ░ ░ ░ ░ ▒   ░    ░  
echo ░  ░   ░           ░  ░   ░        ░ ░   ░    ░                 
echo                                   ░
```

Then I saved the file as `demo.cmd`, making sure `Encoding: UTF-8` is selected, and then I ran it.

Here's the result:

[image: console screenshot]